# How to use background queue for Google Drive service in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, background, google-drive-api

According to [documentation](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki#threading) of [google-api-objectivec-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client) library:

> Queries made from any thread can be called back on a background thread by providing a background queue, as in this example:
>
> ```
> service.delegateQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
> ```
>
> When a delegate queue is specified, there is no requirement for a run loop to be running on the thread that executes the query.

But, it does not work. Handlers are still executed on a main thread.

### Question:

How to tell Google Drive service to execute handlers on the background thread?

#### Code snippet to reproduce

Podfile:

```
pod 'GTMOAuth2'
pod 'GoogleAPIClient/Drive'
```

Somewhere in application:

```
#import "GTLDrive.h"
#import "GTMOAuth2Authentication.h"

...

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *) aNotification {
    service = [[GTLServiceDrive alloc] init];
    service.retryEnabled = YES;
    service.authorizer = _authorizer //from GTMOAuth2WindowController
    service.delegateQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    GTLDriveFile * tempadFolder = [GTLDriveFile object];
    folder.name = @"folder-name";
    folder.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
    GTLQueryDrive * query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesCreateWithObject: folder uploadParameters: nil];
    
    [service executeQuery: query completionHandler: 
                                       ^(GTLServiceTicket * ticket,
                                         GTLDriveFile * updatedFile,
                                         NSError * error) {
                                             if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
                                                  NSLog(@"This is a main thread!");
                                             } 
                                         }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/pull/177/commits/3320c1ad4e77b716a7f37cfaa003794efbce9486) and released in `GoogleAPIClient 1.0.2`.


For now code behaves according to documentation:

> Queries made from any thread can be called back on a background thread by providing a background queue, as in this example
>
> ```
> service.delegateQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
> ```